# How does Emissary of Grudges work exactly?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander, mtg-multiplayer

[image: Emissary Of Grudges card image]

I have [Emissary of Grudges](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEmissary%20of%20Grudges%5d) in my deck and I was wondering if I use it correctly. In exemple:

I play Emissary of Grudges and I secretly choose player 2.

Player 2's turn. He casts [Clone](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bClone%5d) and targets me with its ability:

> You may have Clone enter the battlefield as a copy of any creature on the battlefield.

First question: **Can I use Emissary of Grudges's ability as an instant?**

If so, **can I "cancel" Clone's ability, and use it myself on anyone?**

In example, could I choose to target Player 3? Or am I forced to use it on its owner?

Last question: **if Emissary of Grudges leaves the battlefield, do I keep this ability? Or do I just throw out the chosen player's name?**

Thank you!

Comment: The second question is a duplicate of https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/43995/which-spells-or-abilities-are-affected-by-things-that-care-about-targeting. Be careful to not use the word "target" unless the card itself does.

Comment: "Player 2's turn. He casts Clone and targets me with its ability:

You may have Clone enter the battlefield as a copy of any creature on the battlefield" You're a creature on the battlefield?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I use Emissary of Grudges's ability as an instant?

Yes, otherwise it wouldn't make sense. A spell or ability is something on the stack.

> can I "cancel" Clone's ability, and use it myself on anyone?

Nope. Clone's ability doesn't target; the word 'target' has a very specific meaning in Magic and is almost always printed on the card, in the rules text or the reminder text. A similar card which does target is [Rite of Replication](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRite%20of%20Replication%5d), which does not target *you* but it might target a permanent you control. If it does, you can choose another target for that spell, but it must be a creature (for example, a Grizzly Bears; it doesn't matter who owns it) and the controller of the spell doesn't change. The cloned Bears will still be controlled by player 2.

> if Emissary of Grudges leaves the battlefield, do I keep this ability? Or do I just throw out the chosen player's name?

You don't need to reveal it, you can just throw the paper you wrote it on away. If it enters the battlefield again, you can choose a new player.

Comment: But the card says "Target you or a permanent you control" .. ?

Comment: Yup, that means if Player 2 casts a Lightning Bolt on you, you can redirect it to him or a creature he controls.

Comment: Clone doesn't target, it's a choose.