# Is Leyline of Combustion triggered by attacks?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If my opponent attacks me, does that trigger [Leyline of Combustion](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLeyline%20of%20Combustion%5d) to do damage to them? I'm new and need help with this rule. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

No.

Attacking is not casting a spell or activating an ability. It is a separate thing completely. Also, targeting has a specific meaning in Magic; just because you are going after a player does not mean are targeting them.

[See here](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/43995/which-spells-or-abilities-are-affected-by-things-that-care-about-targeting) for more details about what things deal with targeting.