# Does Guttersnipe's ability count as attacking?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Does [Guttersnipe](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGuttersnipe%5d) dealing damage to a player from an instant being played count as it attacking you and therefore triggering [Revenge of Ravens](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRevenge%20of%20Ravens%5d)?

Comment: Related; though not a duplicate: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/48995/is-leyline-of-combustion-triggered-by-attacks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**No, Guttersnipe's ability does not count as "attacking".**

In Magic the word "attacks" as used on Revenge of Ravens specifically refers to declaring a creature as an attacker in combat. Guttersnipe's ability does not do that; it just deals damage to players.

Comment: To add on to this:
It's a good rule of thumb to read into the wording very literally. Modern Magic (including updated oracle text of old cards) is very specific about its wording. "Attack" has one very specific definition, and cards that check for "attacking" only apply to that specific definition. Same goes for casting, drawing, targeting etc. The only thing to watch out for are keyword abilities and card properties that don't include reminder text such as "303.4a An Aura spell requires a target, which is defined by its enchant ability" which is implicit on all auras but not written in text.

Comment: I believe that if a card says "Put this on the battlefield attacking", that's not attacking either.

Comment: @Acccumulation It's a subtly different reason. Revenge of Ravens checks in the declare attackers step, and that's also the earliest point that "Put this on the battlefield attacking" would go on the stack. RoR doesn't re-check once those resolve.

Comment: @Caleth Yeah, I should have said "Does not count as being declared as attacker".

Answer (score 0):

The word attack in magic is very, very specific to a creature being an attacker in the combat step. Any other source of damage is not attacking, be it fight, tap to deal damage, or any other less common effect.

For the purpose of "whenever a creature attacks" it's even more restricted, there are effects that create creatures already attacking, like [Hero of Bladehold](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHero%20of%20Bladehold%5d), these tokens created "tapped and attacking" were never declared as attackers, so they get by the restrictions from things like [Crawlspace](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCrawlspace%5d) and do not trigger things like [Revenge of Ravens](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRevenge%20of%20Ravens%5d).

This trigger is talked about in the [comprehensive rules](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Declare_attackers_step):

> **508.3a** An ability that reads “Whenever [a creature] attacks, . . .” triggers if that creature is declared as an attacker. Similarly, “Whenever [a creature] attacks [a player or planeswalker], . . .” triggers if that creature is declared as an attacker attacking that player or planeswalker. Such abilities won’t trigger if a creature is put onto the battlefield attacking.