# Color Protection Attacking Creature vs hexproof Blocking Creature

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Let's says I'm blocking with a [Hitchclaw Recluse](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHitchclaw%20Recluse%5d) (a green spider with reach that is a 1/4) and I have cast the instant [Woodcutter's Grit](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWoodcutter%27s%5d%2b%5bGrit%5d) which targets the Hitchclaw recluse giving it +3/+3 + hexproof. So now it's a 4/7 hexproof reach spider blocking a [Coast Watcher](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCoast%20Watcher%5d), a bird soldier with flying and protection from green and my opponent had cast [Inspired Charge](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bInspired%20Charge%5d) in retaliation.

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Answer (score 8):

Hitchclaw Recluse can't block Coast Watcher, even though it has reach.

One of the qualities offered by protection from green is that the creature can't be blocked by green creatures. Hexproof doesn't matter; the spider isn't being targeted by Coast Watcher. So the other instants cast don't matter.

Comment: Since I put hexproof on my green spider wouldn't that effect the protection from Green since it makes it so it can not be a targeted by the Spells or abilities and protection from Green would be in ability of that card ?

Comment: @Zatch Ironhammer, Protection from Green is an ability, but it doesn't target. *702.11b “Hexproof” on a permanent means “This permanent can’t be the target of spells or abilities your opponents control.”* *702.16b A permanent or player with protection can’t be targeted by spells with the stated quality and can’t be targeted by abilities from a source with the stated quality.*

Comment: @ZatchIronhammer See this question for more info on what it means to "target" something: [Which spells or abilities are affected by things that care about targeting?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/43995/which-spells-or-abilities-are-affected-by-things-that-care-about-targeting)

Comment: If, somehow, Hitchclaw Recluse did block Coast Watcher (perhaps because Hitchclaw Recluse had its color changed when blockers were declared and then had its color changed again back to green before damage was dealt): when damage is dealt, Hitchclaw Recluse would be dealt 3 damage (Coast Watcher is a 3/2), and Coast Watcher would be dealt 0 damage (protection from green means it can't be dealt damage by green sources). Barring any other actions, both creatures would survive.